# ndb window not showing anything

Tags: node.js, npm

I've searched and searched, trying to figure this one out, but I'm stumped, along with everyone on my team.

I went through the extremely simple instructions to install ndb globally on a mac mojave setup - simple `npm install -g ndb`. All went without a hitch, so I went to run a js file through it. Example `ndb .` or `ndb test/mytest.js`. The ndb window opens up just fine, but it is completely blank. There's no indication that it is attached to the given file/location, and it isn't actually running the file (which has debugger statements, so I would expect it to stop).

Here's an example of what I see when I run `ndb .` in my project's root directory:

[image: example window]

I've tried installing this locally to the project, reinstalling globally, trying different ndb flags and commands, all producing the same general result. It appears that opening this window always finds the NPM Scripts just fine, but running those, or a file doesn't seem to do anything.

If I keep the window open for awhile, eventually this happens in the console - I'm not sure if it is related or not.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[9414:0x103000000]   277347 ms: Mark-sweep 1412.9 (1506.0) -> 1412.9 (1476.5) MB, 1311.4 / 0.2 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 1311 ms) last resort GC in old space requested
[9414:0x103000000]   278661 ms: Mark-sweep 1412.9 (1476.5) -> 1412.9 (1476.5) MB, 1313.5 / 0.3 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x5fc058a5ee1 <JSObject>
    1: onParseComplete [internal/url.js:~199] [pc=0x1300474ba0a8](this=0x5fcd08dc0d9 <URL map = 0x5fcfb52b811>,flags=1424,protocol=0x5fcd08dc131 <String[5]: file:>,username=0x5fc43102311 <undefined>,password=0x5fc43102311 <undefined>,host=0x5fc43102471 <String[0]: >,port=0x5fc43102201 <null>,path=0x5fcd08dc151 <JSArray[8]>,query=0x5fc43102201 <null>,fragment=0x5fcbb8364c1 <String[68]: /index.js/i...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/Users/stuart/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/Users/stuart/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/Users/stuart/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/Users/stuart/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInTargetSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/stuart/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node]
 6: 0x13004730463d
```

Any help or ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have something to do with your node version. I had the same problem with node v10.7.0. After an upgrade to v11.6.0 it started working again.

Comment: That could be the issue. Unfortunately I can't upgrade in this environment, but that might be the only option to get this running.